# SSRS Data Driven Subscription Option Not Appearing

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We have a new 2016 report server. It is supposedly the **Enterprise Edition** but Data Driven Subscriptions are not available in our PROD database but they are available in our TEST server.

I know that versions lower than the Enterprise Edition do not have Data Driven Subscriptions but our Operations department says that the servers are set up the same.

Unfortunately, I do not have access to check out the server edition (or much else) myself so I can't say for sure that the PROD server is the Enterprise Edition. Our Ops guys haven't done much with SSRS - I had to tell one guy where to set up the e-mail server so the e-mail **Destination** appeared.

### TEST SERVER with data driven subscription:

[image]

Is there any reason, other than not having the Enterprise Edition, that could make the Data Driven subscriptions to not appear? Is there a setting or an option that needs to be checked during installation?

Comment: are you able to do a simple Select @@version in SQL Management Studio against your prod environment and  compare it to your test environment.. that should tell you what version straight away.. or connect to the reporting server instance and then look at server properties.. Edition

Comment: Thanks @Harry - I was able to get a DBA to run it on PROD and it is the Standard version while our DEV server has the Developers Edition (ugh). That's what I suspected but didn't know if there are other reasons that the Data Driven subscriptions might not be available.

Comment: Glad to be of help.. I'll put my comment up as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no setting (as far as I am aware) that would disable the Data Driven Subscription option from appearing on your subscription window by default.

Simple Select @@version in SQL Management Studio against your prod environment and compare it to your test environment.. that should tell you what version straight away.. or connect to the reporting server instance and then look at server properties.. Edition., It's got to be the version!

Comment: Thanks Harry. I thought that was the case but our junior Ops guy was telling me that they were the same edition. I didn't realize that the Developers Edition would have the Data Driven subscriptions while we only had the Standard Edition. Seems like having a DEV version that's different than PROD would cause more problems than it solves.